# PHP Image editing (am I doing it wrong ?)

Tags: php, imagemagick

I need to resize and stitch togehter 7 images, for that I'm using ImageMagick but it's oughly heavy and takes a long time to perform. Is there any other lighter library I can use ?
Or perhaps my code is to blame:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$thumb = new Imagick();
$thumb->newImage(128*7,128, 'black');
$thumb->borderImage( 'purple', 1, 1 );

$images = new Imagick(glob('*.jpg'));

$counter =0;
foreach($images as $image) {

    // Providing 0 forces thumbnailImage to maintain aspect ratio
    $image->thumbnailImage(128,128, true);
    $thumb->compositeImage($image,Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, (128*$counter)+(64-$image->getImageWidth()/2),64-$image->getImageHeight()/2);//echo $image;

    $counter++;
}
$thumb->setImageFormat('jpeg');
echo $thumb;    

?>
```

**UPDATE:**
As it is for an iPhone app I decided to do the resizing and stitching on the iPhone itself (and  then upload the result to the server for future use).

Comment: From my understanding the GD is much heavier than imagemagick (http://sven.webiny.com/php-gd-vs-imagemagick-benchmark/)

Comment: It works faster (as far as my experience shows) with smaller images but works awfully with larger images. I've not tested GD specially. By the way GMagick must have better performance than both of them. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm writing an iPhone app and my resources on the server are low I decided to do the "hard" work on the iphone's side.

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I do not use imagick but use Imagemagick command line with php exec() and you can speed up jpg resizing using define as a "hint". I belive it only reads enough of the input image to create the output image.

Anyway there was a post on the Imagemagick forum a couple of weeks ago about speeding up jpg resizing with Imagick and the answer was:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setOption('jpeg:size', '800x532');
$image->readImage('origional.jpg');
```

I am not sure how this would work in your case and the original thread is:
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=20586&hilit=speed

Comment: Though it does seem faster I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation. It does not restrict itself to 128X128 (as I set it to) to keep aspect ratio but rather resized the image I tested it on to 128X180.

Comment: Imagick is not very well supported or documented. It is not written or maintained by the Imagemagick developers. The line $image->setOption('jpeg:size', '800x532'); does not resize the image it just lets imagick know that is to be the final size image and as I said restricts the image data read in from the original image. I do not use Imagick and can not add any further advice - sorry.

Comment: I didn't even know there was Imagick and ImageMagick...
I do appreciate you trying to help :)

Comment: If you want to try Imagemagick with php and command line have a look at the examples on my site: www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick As soon as I found there was a program for php called Imagick I knew it would cause confusion! But it looks like you have a method that works on the phone now anyway.